# R - How to simplify this text clean-up of special characters?

Tags: r, text, replace, text-mining, tm

I suspect there is a way to simplify this text pre-preprocessing. However, I could not find a solution how to merge all these character replacements into a single row. Hence, to avoid all the repetition in my current solution (see below):

```
Encoding(posts2$caption_clean) <- "UTF-8"
posts2$caption_clean <- iconv(posts2$caption_clean, "latin1", "UTF-8")
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ã\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("â\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("ð\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Â\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("å\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ð\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ñ\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ù\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ø\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Ú\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("ì\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Õ\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("ã\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("Û\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean) 
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("ë\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("ê\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
posts2$caption_clean <- gsub("è¿½\\S*","",posts2$caption_clean)
```

Does anyone know how I can simplify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to replace ONLY those characters? If not, there are general solutions in the SO archives. Otherwise you could write a small function that iterates over your data and replaces all specified characters.

Comment: Yes, put all the bad strings in a single character vector, and loop over it in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks. The loop would do, indeed. Ideally, I would have a general solution. Is there a name for the above characters (so I can find it SO archives)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# construct regex where each target pattern is a group ()
# enclose groups in [] to target any of those groups

regex <- "[(Ã\\S*)(â\\S*)(ð\\S*)]" 
string <- "Ã  x â x ð y "
gsub(regex, "", string)
```

result:

```
[1] "  x  x  y "
```